# Use 'throws Exception' from Buttons - Java

Tags: java, swing, exception

I am getting the system's MAC Address and for that i need to use

```
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception {
```

but due to some reasons i want to move that code to when someone presses a certain button. I am able to copy the code but i am not able to

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
```

to

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) throws Exception
```

It gives a system sound and the line seems uneditable,

I am using this in the code `Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();`

Here is my main code:

```
String[] macArray = new String[1000];
      macArray[0] = "74 E5 43 23 F1 B4 ";
      macArray[1] = "74 E5 43 24 5F 18 ";
      int i=0;
      String[] current = new String[1000];

     Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();

    while (interfaces.hasMoreElements())
    {
      NetworkInterface nif = interfaces.nextElement();
      byte[] lBytes = nif.getHardwareAddress();
      StringBuffer lStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

      if (lBytes != null)
      {
        for (byte b : lBytes)
        {
          lStringBuffer.append(String.format("%1$02X ", new Byte(b)));
        }
      }
      current[i]=lStringBuffer.toString();
      System.out.println(lStringBuffer);
      i++;

      //System.out.println(lStringBuffer)
    }

    for(; i<1000; i++){
        current[i]= "" + 0;
    }
    int te=0;
    for(int j=0; j<1000; j++){
        for(int k=0; k<1000; k++){
            if(current[j].equals(macArray[k])){
                System.out.println("WOW!!!");
                te=1;
            }
        }
        //System.out.println(current[j]);
    }
    if(te!=1){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error");
        System.exit(0);

    }
```

Comment: Don't throw the exception. Catch it and handle it.

Comment: @Marcelo How exactly Sir?

Comment: You can learn a little more of handling exceptions in this part of the Java tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html

Comment: @Marcelo Sir do you mean i should try and put "try and catch"

Comment: @Marcelo Sir would putting the following code in try{} and inserting catch (UnknownHostException e) {
 
  e.printStackTrace();
 
 } HELP?(I mean should i do this????)

Comment: @Marcelo It Worked! Thanks. Now will you write an answer or can i write an answer?

Comment: You can do it @Daksh.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the `throws` clause of a method you override. The base interface declared no checked exceptions, so a derived class cannot suddenly start throwing them without violating the contract. The private method you name does not by itself override any such method, but it seems there is a nested callback class somewhere in your code which does implement `ActionListener`, and apparently your IDE is making sure you play nice with that.

You basically have two solutions. Both start by catching the exception within the callback. Then you can either try to handle the thing reasonably, e.g. by showing an error message, or even terminating the application. Up to you. The minimal solution would be something like this:

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        // do stuff
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // ignore error otherwise, if we can safely do so.
    }
}
```

If you *definitely* want the exception to pop up outside that callback, you'll have to wrap it into an *unchecked* exception, i.e. one derived from `RuntimeException`. Make your own subclass for the purpose. An unchecked exception can pass through code without having to be declared. Now you must be extra careful that you will catch that exception eventually. Without further action, the default exception handler of the AWT GUI thread will simply print a stack trace and ignore the exception. This is dangerous, since it might leave your application in an inconsistent state, unless your code is written to properly handle such unexpected stack unwindings and partially executed methods. And if all you wanted is a stack trace, printing that from the handler itself would be a lot cleaner. To do something else, you'd likely have to [change the default exception handler for that thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29) (perhaps obtained via [`EventQueue.invokeAndWait`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29)) or [all threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29).